# Tablet with HDMI output recommendations

Tags: hdmi, tablet

Are there any tablets that have an upscaled 1080p HDMI output to a 1080p resolution screen?

The intended use is for playing private videos from a tablet to a TV.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iPad and this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Apple-Lightning-Digital-AV-Adapter/dp/B009WHV3BM/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=lightning+to+hdmi&qid=1614028449&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009WHV3BM)

Or you could use any android tablet and a Chromecast for mirroring.  Works very well.

Comment: Can a chromecast mirror any android device?

Comment: Pretty much any modern device like a Samsung tablet.  Maybe not a cheap RCA Walmart tablet.

Comment: So from here, https://tinyurl.com/1cdgdp6v, it says at least an Android 5.0 or higher, and I assume at least the device needs wifi and/or bluetooth. And also from here, https://tinyurl.com/2u6h8sf9, it seems that Chromecast would have significant limitations, like not being able to mirror your own private video files at 1080p from phone to the screen. // I've also tried with an old existing iPad but the output resolution was limited to the iPad's resolution and didn't upscale to the TV's.

Comment: Ok, if you’re trying to use private videos chrome cast would not be optimal unless you are using Google photos.  What’s your budget for a tablet?